# Remove dynamically added Label on FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, flowlayoutpanel

I have dynamically add **Label** on **FlowLayoutPanel**, with the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label lb = new Label();
        lb.Text = "How are You";
        lb.Size = new Size(650, Font.Height +10);
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lb);
        flowLayoutPanel1.SetFlowBreak(lb, true);
        lb.BackColor = Color.Wheat;
    }
```

In **ContextMenuStrip** I have add two Item Add and Edit and associate it **FlowLayoutPanel**, mean when user right click on the **FlowLayoutPanel**, Edit and Remove menu appears.

Now I want to delete the dynamically add Label using remove button (ContextMenuStrip ). I want to just right click on the desire lebel and after right click it should be removed. and the same case with Edit button for edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

keep a reference to your lb variable around on the form (instead of just inside the function).  When you want to remove it, call flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(lb).

You should add an event handler to the label in the same sub where it is called for the label's right click event.  Inside this handler is where the above call to .Remove should be.

Alternatively, since the event handler will pass the sender object in, which will be reference to the control that the event fired on, you can just call .Remove and pass in sender.  you won't have to keep a reference to the label around this way unless you need it for something else.

**Requested Example**

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove((ToolStripMenuItem) sender);
```

**Edited again after comments**

I changed your button1's click event to

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     lb = new Label();
    lb.Text = "How are You";
    lb.Size = new Size(650, Font.Height +10);
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lb);
    flowLayoutPanel1.SetFlowBreak(lb, true);
    lb.BackColor = Color.Wheat;
    lb.MouseEnter += labelEntered;
}
```

as you can see I added a MouseEntered event handler to catch the last label that the mouse was over.

I added the following sub, which is handler mentioned above.  All it does it record the last label that the mouse was over.

```
private Label lastLabel;
private void labelEntered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lastLabel = (Label)sender;
}
```

The code for the remove button has been changed to this.

```
public void Remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lastLabel != null)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(lastLabel);
        lastLabel = null;
    }
}
```

First thing it does it check to make sure that lastLabel has a value, if it does it removes the last label that the mouse was over, then clears the lastLabel variable.

Comment: flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(lb) is functioning correct on single label, but when I add multiple label with same button(Mean Button Press Twice , it add two label) then it remove only last one. But I want , when I right click on the desire Label it should remove not last one.

Comment: I wasn't aware you were going to add multiple of the "Same label". Doing so will overwrite the previous instance with the newly created one. try the 2nd method i mentioned, where you remove Sender.  you will probably have cast sender to a control, it should work no matter how many you add.

Comment: If your provide me code as an example , then perhaps I understand your second alternative solution practically. I understand what are you saying but i can not implement it without code because of new in c#. So, sample code will be appreciable. and thanks for respond

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example.  Just replace the previous call to remove I gave you with this one.

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'.

Comment: InvalidCastException was unhandled

Comment: private void Remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove((Label)sender);
        }

Comment: Same Error if I use Control  --  Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'.    --   public void Remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove((Control)sender);
        }

Comment: ok, lets hit it with a hammer this time. Try (ToolStripMenuItem) instead of (Control).

Comment: flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove((ToolStripMenuItem)sender);  complete line, underline with red color.

Comment: ok, give me a minute to actually try this in visual studio. I'll get back to you in about 15 minutes or so.

Comment: Are you right-clicking on the label that you are trying to remove? Or some other control?

Comment: OK Dear, I am using Visual 2010 Premium. Thanks for coordination

Comment: I have just only labels, I add multiple labels on pressing one button as I mentioned the code above, I have no other control currently. and I right click on label and then click on remove

Comment: Would it be possible for you to zip up your project and email it to bradley.uffner@gmail.com?

Comment: Ahhh! I see, you are using a context menu, and not directly removing the label on the label's right click.  That explains why the sender reference is pointing to the wrong control.  if you zip up your project and send it to me at the above email address I would be more than happy to help you out.  Unfortunately this isn't going to be a simple fix like I originally thought.

Comment: ok, I have a solution for you.  I am updating my answer with the changes, and also sending the modified solution back to you.

Comment: Thanks Bradley Uffner, Problem Solved !